# A shorter way to write System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been focusing on logging more lately. I really do appreciate getting the method name in the logger. My only issue is that the reflective method is so long to write.

I tested with static classes and a method for it. But to my not so big surprise, it gave me the name of the static class method.

So far the only way I found to shorten it a bit is

```
using Info = System.Reflection.MethodBase;
string name = Info.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Is there a way to shorten this to something like `Info.MethodName()`?

Comment: Not directly relative to the question though, I think you may want to try [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Well, it did shorten it to what i wanted. So thank you so much

Comment: Also CallerMemberName is much more performant as it doesn't use reflection, but the compiler directly inserts the method name at compile time as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

After following tips from Leisen Chang tips about using CallerMemberName solved it with a static class.

```
public static class Info
{
    public static string MethodName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```